# ImportError: No module named mako

Tags: python

I have installed of python in 2 different location. I have opened two terminals setting environment variable such a way that each terminal finds a different python installation:

```
TERM1$which python
/A/python

TERM2$which python
/B/python
```

Later, I installed `Mako` using one of the installations (I don't remember which one). I installed mako locally using:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

My understanding was that, the module will go to the PATH given by:

```
$python -c 'import site; print site.USER_SITE'
/home/.../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

which points to the same location in my `/home` if I run the above command from *either* of the terminals. 
The problem is that if I run :

```
python -c 'import mako'
```

one of the terminals is OK but the other one gives error:

```
ImportError: No module named mako
```

Most probably, the search path is different from one terminal(env) to another. But I don't know what to check!

Comment: check if something name mako exists under site-packages in any of python installation directory

Comment: but like i said, the mako installation path is same! and it exists!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...in your terminal

$ sudo updatedb 
$ locate mako

Both are different commands.

Locate will give you the exact location of where Mako is installed and under which python version.

Chances are it must be installed only for one of the python versions.

You will have to install it for another one to make it work. You can also try changing alias of python to another one in .bashrc and then install Mako in the changed Python version and then try importing the module.

How to switch to a different python version:- http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Comment: `updatedb: invalid option locate`! but yes!!! your guess is right. `'python --version` is giving me different versions-2.6.x and 2.7. Maybe you want to update your answer so that i can mark it as true?

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: "How to switch to a different python version" resolved it for me. In the Appendix, `update-alternatives`. The module I was using was looking for `python` but on Ubuntu that gets version 2.x. Setting the alternative so `python` used the 3.x version resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

`pip install mako` use this line

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with this error is this:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip libyaml-dev

$ sudo pip install prettytable Mako pyaml dateutils --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Bash version is different from my Apache version:

```
# Bash
$ python3 -c 'import site; print(site.USER_SITE)'
/Users/me/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages

# Apache
/Library/WebServer/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
```

In terminal - mako is imported fine, but via Apache - it cannot find it ( even if i append to `sys.path` the direct path )

the answer above hit me, that Apache's user is different than the Bash user ...
therefore in my case - i had to install the mako module - globally.